# error: 'answer' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c

I need help with this code I don't know what to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


int input(float nom[],float toler[],int SIGN[],char V_F[],float *Spec_Min,float *Spec_Max);

float tolerances(int size, float nom[],float toler[],int SIGN[],char V_F[],float Spec_Min,float Spec_Max);

void adjust(int size, float nom[],float toler[],int SIGN[],char V_F[],float Spec_Min,float Spec_Max, int answer, float *dimension, float *impact, float *DgapMean, float *gaptol, float *newtol, float *newdim);


int main(void)
{
    float nom[70], toler[70], Spec_Min=0, Spec_Max=0;
    int SIGN[70];
    char V_F[70];
    int i, n;
    n = input( nom, toler, SIGN, V_F, &Spec_Min, &Spec_Max);
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        printf("Part: %f, %d, %f, %c\n\n", nom[i], SIGN[i], toler[i], V_F[i]);//printing off all parts and the dimensions tolerances and if the part is fixed or variable
    }
    printf("_______________________\n");
    printf("Gap: %f, %f\n\n", Spec_Min, Spec_Max);//print the size of the gap
    int size = 0;
    size = input( nom, toler, SIGN, V_F, &Spec_Min, &Spec_Max);

    tolerances(size, nom, toler, SIGN, V_F, Spec_Min, Spec_Max);
>line 43 is below this

    adjust( size, nom, toler, SIGN, V_F, Spec_Min, Spec_Max, answer, &dimension, &impact, &DgapMean, &gaptol, &newtol, &newdim);
    return 0;


}

int input(float nom[],float toler[],int SIGN[],char V_F[],float *Spec_Min,float *Spec_Max)
{
    int status, i;
    FILE *FTIN;
    FTIN = fopen ("C:\\EGR107\\input.txt", "r");

    if (FTIN == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR\n");//if the file didnt work show an error
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0;;)
        {
            if((status = fscanf(FTIN," PART,%f,%d,%f,%c", &nom[i], &SIGN[i], &toler[i], &V_F[i]))==4)//scans parts until it doesnt start with part
            {
                ++i;
            }
            else if((status = fscanf(FTIN, " GAP,%f,%f", Spec_Min, Spec_Max))==0)//scans gap after part was scaned
            {
                fgetc(FTIN);
            }
            else if(status == EOF)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(FTIN);
    return i;
}


float tolerances(int size, float nom[],float toler[],int SIGN[],char V_F[],float Spec_Min,float Spec_Max)
    {

    int x;
    float Act_Gap, Act_Toler, Max_Gap = 0.0, Min_Gap = 0.0;
    for ( x=0, Act_Gap = 0; x<size; x++)    //does math for the tolerance
    {
        Act_Gap = Act_Gap + (nom[x]*SIGN[x]);
    }
    for ( x=0, Act_Toler = 0; x<size; x++)
    {
        Act_Toler = Act_Toler + (toler[x]);
    }
    for (x= 0, Max_Gap = 0; x<size; x++)
    {
        Max_Gap = (nom[x]*SIGN[x]+toler[x])+Max_Gap;
        Min_Gap = (nom[x]*SIGN[x]-toler[x])+Min_Gap;
    }
    printf("_______________________\n");
    printf("Actual Gap Mean: %.3f\"\n\n", Act_Gap);  //printing actual gap and gap tolerances
    printf("Actual Gap Tolerance: %.3f\"\n\n", Act_Toler);
    if (Max_Gap > Spec_Max)
    {
        printf("The Maximum gap %.3f\" is Greater than specified %.3f\"\n\n", Max_Gap, Spec_Max);//printing whether or not the max gap is greater than or less than the specified
    }
    if (Max_Gap < Spec_Max)
    {
        printf("The Maximum gap %.3f\" is Less than specified %.3f\"\n\n", Max_Gap, Spec_Max);
    }
    if (Min_Gap > Spec_Min)
    {
        printf("The Minimum gap %.3f\" is Greater than specified %.3f\"\n\n", Min_Gap, Spec_Min);//printing whether or not the min gap is greater than or less than the specified
    }
    if (Min_Gap < Spec_Min)
    {
        printf("The Minimum gap %.3f\" is Less than specified %.3f\"\n\n", Min_Gap, Spec_Min);
    }
    return 0;
}

void adjust(int size, float nom[],float toler[],int SIGN[],char V_F[],float Spec_Min,float Spec_Max,int answer, float *dimension, float *impact, float *DgapMean, float *gaptol, float *newtol, float *newdim)
{

    int i, x, status, change;
    double gapmean, Atolerance, changeinNOM, changeinTOL;

    double Part, TOL;

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        gapmean = gapmean+(dimension[i]*impact[i]);         //gets actual gap of parts
        printf("Gap Mean: %.3f\n", gapmean);
        Atolerance = Atolerance + toler[i];             //gets actual tolerance of parts
        printf("Actual Tolerance: %.3f\n",Atolerance);

    }

    changeinNOM = *DgapMean - gapmean;                  //finds change in the dimension
    printf("Change in nominal value: %.3f\n",changeinNOM);
    changeinTOL = Atolerance - *gaptol;                 //finds change in the tolerance
    printf("Change in tolerance value: %.3f\n",changeinTOL);

    printf("____________________________\n");   //return
    printf("\n");   //return

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(V_F[i] == 'V')      //looks for variable part
        {
            Part = dimension[i] - changeinNOM;          //calculates new dimension of part
            TOL = toler[i] - changeinTOL;           //calculates new tolerance of part
            if(TOL < 0)
            {
                printf("Part %d cannot be changed\n", i+1);
            }
            if(TOL >= 0)
            {
                printf("Part %d will be changed to %.3f\n",i+1,Part);
                printf("Tolerance of Part %d will be changed to %.3f\n",i+1, TOL);
                printf("Would you like to save the changes?\n");
                printf("Please enter a number value 1 for yes or 0 or no.\n");
                do
                {
                    status = scanf("%d", &answer);
                    if(x != 1 && x != 0)
                    {
                        printf("Please enter a number value 1 or 0.\n");
                        fflush(stdin);
                    }
                    if(answer == 1)
                    {
                        change = 1;
                    }
                    else if(answer == 0)
                    {
                        change = 0;
                    }
                }
                while(answer != 1 && answer != 0 || status == 0);

                if(change == 1)
                {
                    newdim[i] = Part;
                    newtol[i] = TOL;
                    printf("New Part dimension: %.3f and new part tolerance: %.3f\n", newdim[i], newtol[i] );
                    printf("Your changes have been made.\n");
                }
                else if(change == 0)
                {
                    printf("Your changes will not be saved.\n");
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Compiler output:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Final_project_12_2_15 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\EGR107\Code_Blocks\Final_project_12_2_15\main.c||In function 'main':|
C:\EGR107\Code_Blocks\Final_project_12_2_15\main.c|43|error: 'answer'   undeclared (first use in this function)|
C:\EGR107\Code_Blocks\Final_project_12_2_15\main.c|43|note: each undeclared  identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in|
C:\EGR107\Code_Blocks\Final_project_12_2_15\main.c|43|error: 'dimension' undeclared (first use in this function)|
C:\EGR107\Code_Blocks\Final_project_12_2_15\main.c|43|error: 'impact' undeclared (first use in this function)|
C:\EGR107\Code_Blocks\Final_project_12_2_15\main.c|43|error: 'DgapMean' undeclared (first use in this function)|
C:\EGR107\Code_Blocks\Final_project_12_2_15\main.c|43|error: 'gaptol' undeclared (first use in this function)|
C:\EGR107\Code_Blocks\Final_project_12_2_15\main.c|43|error: 'newtol' undeclared (first use in this function)|
C:\EGR107\Code_Blocks\Final_project_12_2_15\main.c|43|error: 'newdim' undeclared (first use in this function)|
C:\EGR107\Code_Blocks\Final_project_12_2_15\main.c||In function 'adjust':|
C:\EGR107\Code_Blocks\Final_project_12_2_15\main.c|179|warning: suggest parentheses around '&&' within '||' [-Wparentheses]|
||=== Build failed: 7 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: So declare those variables?

Comment: There are obvious syntax errors in your code.

Comment: You seem to be using function arguments as local variables. Just declare `answer` as a local variable, and remove it from the argument list.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variables in the beginning of the function used in. Leave one empty row after those. Also don't forget to initialize them (somewhere before using their value), otherwise you can get only garbage.

About the warning:

You must take care of the priority in which you want to use the operators. Moreover, both `&&` and `||` are binary operators, so they take 2 arguments. That's why you must put parentheses. Probably like:

```
while(answer != 1 && (answer != 0 || status == 0))
```